# Tag image in svg invisible in FireFox because of using style. How to fix?

Tags: css, svg, cross-browser

There is a difference between displaying  in Firefox and Chrome. As I investigated Chrome takes css into account while displaying image and Firefox not.

html

```
<svg viewBox="-80 0 500 500">
<g>
<g class="node" transform="translate(0,20)" style="opacity: 1;">
<text transform="translate(0,0)"><tspan class="message">Visible in Chrome and Firefox</tspan></text>
<image class="icon" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/diagram_v2/PNG/32x32/diagram_v2-17.png" x="0" y="15" width ="20px" height="20px" ><title>Try to use in Firefox and Chrome.</title> 
</image>
</g>
<g class="node" transform="translate(0,80)" style="opacity: 1;">
<text transform="translate(0,0)"><tspan class="message">Invisible in Firefox</tspan></text>
<image class="icon" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/diagram_v2/PNG/32x32/diagram_v2-17.png" x="0" y="15" ><title>Try to use in Firefox and Chrome.</title> 
</image>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

css

```
.icon {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
.message {
  text-align: left;
  visibility: visible;
  font: 8pt sans-serif;
}
```

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RomanSt/6gawt795/1/) for it. How to push Firefox to use css?

PS: I found related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19693497/svg-image-tag-not-working-in-firefox-or-ie), but I have viewBox in root element.

Comment: You could download the source code to Firefox, implement the change to its C++ source code if you want this. I.e. currently it's just not yet implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SVG 1.1 (the current standard), only [properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/propidx.html) could be styled with CSS.

In the upcoming SVG 2 standard, nearly every attribute will be stylable with CSS. However browsers have only just started implementing this change. Chrome is further along in implementing this than Firefox.

For now, you'll have to do this a different way.  Ie. with attributes `width="20" height="20"`.

Comment: I looked throw some papers and now I have the same opinion that it is the problem of SVG 2 browser support.